# grep [^\.] doesn't work

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file called `test.txt`with contents like below:

```
Si  28.086  Si.bhs
As   74.90000  As.pz-bhs.UPF
```

Here is some of my running of grep

[image]

I just can't understand, why `grep bhs[^\.] test.txt` won't grep the first line? Could someone please explain? Doesn't `[^\.]` represent any character other than dot?

Comment: Run `echo \.` and `echo [^\.]`. Quote your regexes.

Comment: Is there actually a character after `bhs` on the first line? "followed by not dot" is not the same as "not followed by dot"

Comment: @steeldriver isn't there \n or \r after bhs?

Comment: Hi, @muru. I don't get it. Neither `grep bhs[^\\.] test.txt` nor `grep 'bhs[^\\.] ' test.txt` works

Comment: You could explicitly match the end-of-line using `grep 'bhs$'` or (if your `grep` supports PCRE mode) use `grep -P 'bhs(?!\.)'`

Comment: @steeldriver But the problem is that if you done it in notepad++ which also use PCRE, `bhs[^\.]` matches the first bhs

Comment: @steeldriver Or you could try it here https://regex101.com/

Comment: @steeldriver However `grep -P 'bhs[^\\.]' test.txt` doesn't work

Comment: `grep` searches within lines.  The newline character (`\n`) is the _terminator_ of the line, so `[^.]` won't match it. Note that `[^\.]` is actually "any character except _backslash or dot_", as characters are not considered special within character classes

Comment: Hi, @Fox,"search within lines" makes sense, thank you. But why `[^\.]` also contains backslash? Isn't `\.` the escaping of dot?

Comment: Nope. Test it: `printf 'bhs\\xyz\n' | grep 'bhs[^\.]'`.  If your regexp is left unquoted, then your shell eats the backslash before `grep` gets it

Comment: @Fox Thank you very much. I now know `grep` and `grep -P` treat `[^\.]` differently

Comment: @user15964 `grep 'bhs\.'` and `grep 'bhs[^.]'`

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the regex, e.g

```
grep '[^.]' xxx
```

And you don't need to escape dot inside the brackets ..

Comment: Hi, daisy. Why I don't need to escape dot inside brackets?

Comment: @user15964 Because "special characters" lose their special meaning within `[...]`. If you escape it, it will be interpreted as a backslash and a dot separately.